# Animate text updated by Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, chaining

Sorry for the simple question - can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have

```
    $("div." + slot).html("<img width=\"64\" class=\"square\" src=\"" + data.newimg + " \">", function() {
    $("div." + slot).fadeIn(2000);  });
```

I would expect this callback function() to animate my DIV that I'm updating with new HTML (adding the image).  It doesn't seem to do anything...

Thanks in advance.

----UPDATE-----

Shouldn't this work?

```
    $("div." + slot)
        .html("<img width=\"64\" class=\"square\" src=\"" + data.newimg + " \">")
        .fadeIn(5000);
```

I also tried:

```
    $("div." + slot)
    .html("<img width=\"64\" class=\"square\" src=\"" + data.newimg + " \">")
    $("div." + slot + " img").fadeIn(5000);
```

Neither seem to give any fade in effect...

Answer (score 0):

.html() has no callback function

use it like this

```
$("div." + slot).html("<img width=\"64\" class=\"square\" src=\"" + data.newimg + " \">");
$("div." + slot).fadeIn(2000);
```

or

```
$("div." + slot)
   .html("<img width=\"64\" class=\"square\" src=\"" + data.newimg + " \">")
   .fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Thanks genesis - see my updated code in the post - I thought I modified as you suggested and it doesn't give a fade effect

Comment: Hmm...not sure what's going wrong. Sounds like it's on my side though. My other jquery stuff works ok, so I know my jquery library is ok.  I think maybe I need the img to fade instead of the div - not sure if my second code I posted works for that

Comment: the image is inside that div referenced - like <div class="slot1"><img src=...></div>

Answer (score 0):

As genesis mentioned, html has no callback, have you tried:

```
$('div.'+slot).html('<img width="64" class="square" src="'+data.newimg+'">').fadeIn(5000);
```

If that doesn't work, the next thing I would check is to make sure your $('div.'+slot) exists at the time you try to change the html.

Comment: Thanks barnzy - what's weird is the first jquery works to modify the src= with the new variable, but the fadein doesn't fade like it seems it should.  i wish i had an example page, it's a private page right now, but maybe I can make it open for a few.

Comment: hmmm, it would be good to see an example in that case, if you could it would really help the debugging, can you not post something similar on JSFiddle?